# "You tried to have him killed" vs "You had someone kill him" vs "You told someone to kill him"

Tags: difference

I am curious about the nuances among the 3 sentences below. OP is the first sentence from an English lecture. I have no idea of the actual context.

> You tried to have him killed.

> You had someone kill him.

> You told someone to kill him.

Comment: The second one cannot be true, since dead people cannot formulate statements.

Comment: The _have_ causative construction is completive. That is, if you _have someone do something_, it got done, and until it gets done, you haven't _had it done_. So if you had someone kill you, you must be dead now. This poses a grammatical problem for the sentence _I had someone kill me_. One must be careful in choosing example sentences when presenting a question.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey OMD...surely in LaLa land the phrase might be possible in one of their non-stop ghost movies and series.

Comment: @Cascabel - I think it is said more than once in _American Horror Story_.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey ...not a fan, but surely that is a good source for the OP should they decide to do some research.

Comment: The _Coven_ series is good, they have Stevie Nicks! Evan Peters is always funny.

Comment: Hi, there is edition by someone.

Original 3 sentences are; 
You tried to have me killed.

You had someone kill me.

You told someone to kill me.

Comment: Ah sorry, now I am clear of why there is edition. Because "You had someone kill me" is impossible because I am dead already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You tried to have him killed. = You tried to kill him by asking someone else to do it, but you didn't manage. *He is still alive.*

> You had someone kill him. = You asked someone to kill him, and that someone did do it. *He is dead.*

> You told someone to kill him. = You asked someone to kill him, but it is not clear whether that someone has done it or not. *He can be dead or alive.*

Still, the examples are not the best...

Comment: You tried to have him killed. = You tried to kill him by asking someone else to do it, but you didn't manage. He is still alive.
--> I want to know how to know "you didn't manage. He is still alive."... 
Is it because of "tried" verb?... If you can make it successful to kill him, I would not use "tried" verb?

Comment: Yes, in that case you wouldn't say _You tried to have him punished_ but simply _You had him punished_.

Comment: You told someone to kill him. = You asked someone to kill him, but it is not clear whether that someone has done it or not. He can be dead or alive. --> I want to know why it is not clear whether he can be dead or alive... Is it owing to the basic meaning of tell?

Comment: Because the emphasis of the sentence is on _**told**_. If you tell someone to do something, it doesn't necessarily mean they will do it. That's common sense in any language I guess...

Comment: Wow thank so much, fev !!!! :D